# Visual C++, Extract text information from a DLL database (sentence mining)

Tags: c, visual-c++, encryption, dll, decompiler

The 2006 version of the free offline Chinese sentence dictionary Jukuu contains a collection of 100,000 publicly sourced example sentences in Chinese and English in a .dll file.

The application size is about 80mb, but once installed a 500mb DLL dictionary file is created with the source text. For whatever reason the application doesn't run on my computer, and I'd like to extract all the example sentences so I can do some POS analysis on them.

Opening the 500mb .DLL file is mostly gibberish, except for some fragments of text here and there and references to other resources.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can extract the information in plain text?

The application can be downloaded here: http://www.jukuu.com/down/download.html

Thanks!

Edit: Never-mind, It looks like when viewed in HEX, the file is ordered in a way that is not conducive to sentence mining at all:

> 00 06 00 02 00 07 03 00  01 00 00 00 FF FE 6E 65  76 65 72 7E 73 74 61
>   6E  64 20 75 70 0B 00 00 80  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  FF FE 33 30 32
>   32 31 38  32 36 38 2D 00 16 00 06  00 02 00 07 03 00 01 00  00 00 FF
>   FE 65 78 74 72  65 6D 65 6C 79 7E 63 6C  6F 73 65 0B 00 00 80 00  00
>   00 00 00 00 00

Something like ÿþnever~stand upÿþ302218268-ÿþextremely~close

Any other ideas on how to mine sentences from the application? Maybe a batch script?

Comment: they don't provide the method name to extract the info?

Comment: Maybe you could use some DLL spy to find possible entry points into the DLL to get information what to call to perform the extraction?

Comment: Looks like it uses the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library, there are two other DLLs, The database is Sent.dll, then there is SentRender.dll and SentSearcher.dll. There is also a ChsTokenize.dll.